# How to use a union to show rolled up values

Tags: sql, db2, union

[image: Notice top row does that have desired outcome]I am using DB2 Syntax and hoping to use a `UNION` to create an additional row to show the rolled up values.

Rather than doing that the first portion of the union is merely naming the columns, whereas the data from the second union appears.

Here is the first portion

```
SELECT 'DRIVER ID' AS DRIVER_ID, 'NAME' AS NAME, 'PUNIT' AS PUNIT, 'PHONE' AS PHONE, 1767 AS TERMINAL_NUMBER, 'DRIVER TYPE' AS DRIVER_TYPE, 
COALESCE((SELECT ROUND(DEC(SUM(CASE WHEN UPDATED_BY IN ('VISTAR','TM4WIN') THEN 1.00 ELSE 0.00 END))/COUNT(UPDATED_BY),2) FROM ODRSTAT, TLORDER L, DRIVER D WHERE DETAIL_LINE_ID = ORDER_ID AND STATUS_CODE IN ('ARRV@SHIP', 'ARRV@CONS', 'DEPT@SHIP', 'DEPT@CONS') 
AND CURRENT_STATUS IN ('EDIBILLED','BILLD') AND L.PICK_UP_DRIVER = D.DRIVER_ID AND 
D.TERMINAL_NUMBER IN (SELECT UNIQUE FIRST_FIELD_INSERT FROM SITE WHERE FAX_PHONE_NUMBER = :DIVISION) AND BILL_DATE BETWEEN CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH AND CURRENT DATE AND ACTUAL_DELIVERY > ACTUAL_PICKUP +30 SECONDS),0) AVG_STATUS_UPDATE,
ROUND(((SELECT MAX(ODOMETER)-MIN(ODOMETER) FROM ODOHIST O 
WHERE READINGDATE >= CURRENT DATE - 30 DAYS AND O.UNIT_ID IN (SELECT UNIT_ID FROM PUNIT WHERE ACTIVE_WHERE = 'D' AND FLEET_ID IN (SELECT UNIQUE USER5 FROM SITE WHERE FAX_PHONE_NUMBER = :DIVISION)))
/(SELECT NULLIF(SUM(T2.VOL_PFUEL),0) FROM FC_POS T2 INNER JOIN DRIVER D ON T2.DRIVER_ID = D.DRIVER_ID 
WHERE D.TERMINAL_NUMBER IN (SELECT UNIQUE FIRST_FIELD_INSERT FROM SITE WHERE FAX_PHONE_NUMBER = :DIVISION)  AND POS_DATE >= CURRENT DATE - 30 DAYS)),2)  AVG_MPG,
(SELECT ROUND(AVG(TIMES),2) FROM (SELECT DELIVERY_DRIVER, ROUND(AVG(DEC((DAYS(CHECKIN_DATE) - DAYS(ACTUAL_DELIVERY)) *24 + (HOUR(CHECKIN_DATE) - HOUR(ACTUAL_DELIVERY)))/24),2) TIMES
FROM LIST_CHECKIN_AUDIT, LYNX.TLORDER WHERE LYNX.TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER = LIST_CHECKIN_AUDIT.BILL_NUMBER AND BILL_DATE >= CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 1 MONTH
AND LYNX.TLORDER.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'INVOICE' AND ACTUAL_DELIVERY < CHECKIN_DATE AND ACTUAL_DELIVERY BETWEEN CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 6 MONTHS AND CURRENT TIMESTAMP + 3 DAYS
GROUP BY LYNX.TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER, DELIVERY_DRIVER) AVERAGES WHERE AVERAGES.DELIVERY_DRIVER IN (SELECT DRIVER_ID FROM DRIVER WHERE ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True' AND TERMINAL_NUMBER IN (SELECT UNIQUE FIRST_FIELD_INSERT FROM SITE WHERE FAX_PHONE_NUMBER = :DIVISION))) AS AVG_DAYS_TO_SCAN,
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN VARCHAR(COALESCE((SELECT DATA FROM CUSTOM_DATA WHERE SRC_TABLE_KEY = DRIVER_ID AND CUSTDEF_ID = '50'),'False' ),10) = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS DRIVE_AXLE,
(SELECT COUNT(UNIQUE A.BILL_NUMBER) FROM LIST_CHECKIN_AUDIT A INNER JOIN TLORDER T ON T.BILL_NUMBER = A.BILL_NUMBER 
WHERE CURRENT_STATUS IN ('EDIBILLED','BILLD') AND COALESCE(PICK_UP_DRIVER,DELIVERY_DRIVER) IN (SELECT DRIVER_ID FROM DRIVER WHERE ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True' 
AND TERMINAL_NUMBER IN (SELECT UNIQUE FIRST_FIELD_INSERT FROM SITE WHERE FAX_PHONE_NUMBER = :DIVISION)) AND BILL_DATE >= CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH AND A.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'DABL') AS DRIVERAXLE_SUBMISSIONS
FROM DRIVER WHERE ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True' 
AND TERMINAL_NUMBER IN (SELECT UNIQUE FIRST_FIELD_INSERT FROM SITE WHERE FAX_PHONE_NUMBER = :DIVISION) 

UNION ALL

SELECT DRIVER_ID, NAME, DEFAULT_PUNIT AS PUNIT, VARCHAR(USER9,12) AS PHONE, TERMINAL_NUMBER, DRIVER_TYPE,
COALESCE((SELECT ROUND(DEC(SUM(CASE WHEN UPDATED_BY IN ('VISTAR','TM4WIN') THEN 1.00 ELSE 0.00 END))/COUNT(UPDATED_BY),2) FROM ODRSTAT, TLORDER L WHERE DETAIL_LINE_ID = ORDER_ID AND STATUS_CODE IN ('ARRV@SHIP', 'ARRV@CONS', 'DEPT@SHIP', 'DEPT@CONS') 
AND CURRENT_STATUS IN ('EDIBILLED','BILLD') AND L.PICK_UP_DRIVER = DRIVER_ID AND BILL_DATE BETWEEN CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH AND CURRENT DATE AND ACTUAL_DELIVERY > ACTUAL_PICKUP +30 SECONDS),0) AS STATUS_UPDATE_PERCENT,
ROUND(((SELECT MAX(ODOMETER)-MIN(ODOMETER) FROM ODOHIST O 
WHERE READINGDATE >= CURRENT DATE - 30 DAYS AND O.UNIT_ID = DEFAULT_PUNIT)/(SELECT NULLIF(SUM(T2.VOL_PFUEL),0) FROM FC_POS T2 WHERE T2.DRIVER_ID = DRIVER.DRIVER_ID AND POS_DATE >= CURRENT DATE - 30 DAYS)),2) AS MPG_30DAYS,
(SELECT ROUND(AVG(TIMES),2) FROM (SELECT DELIVERY_DRIVER, ROUND(AVG(DEC((DAYS(CHECKIN_DATE) - DAYS(ACTUAL_DELIVERY)) *24 + (HOUR(CHECKIN_DATE) - HOUR(ACTUAL_DELIVERY)))/24),2) TIMES
FROM LIST_CHECKIN_AUDIT, LYNX.TLORDER WHERE LYNX.TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER = LIST_CHECKIN_AUDIT.BILL_NUMBER AND BILL_DATE >= CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 1 MONTH
AND LYNX.TLORDER.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'INVOICE' AND ACTUAL_DELIVERY < CHECKIN_DATE AND ACTUAL_DELIVERY BETWEEN CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 6 MONTHS AND CURRENT TIMESTAMP + 3 DAYS
GROUP BY LYNX.TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER, DELIVERY_DRIVER) AVERAGES WHERE AVERAGES.DELIVERY_DRIVER = DRIVER.DRIVER_ID)
 AVG_DAYS_TO_SCAN,
VARCHAR(COALESCE((SELECT DATA FROM CUSTOM_DATA WHERE SRC_TABLE_KEY = DRIVER_ID AND CUSTDEF_ID = '50'),'False' ),10) AS DRIVEAXLE, 
(SELECT COUNT(UNIQUE A.BILL_NUMBER) FROM LIST_CHECKIN_AUDIT A INNER JOIN TLORDER T ON T.BILL_NUMBER = A.BILL_NUMBER 
WHERE CURRENT_STATUS IN ('EDIBILLED','BILLD') AND COALESCE(PICK_UP_DRIVER,DELIVERY_DRIVER) = DRIVER_ID AND BILL_DATE >= CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH AND A.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'DABL') AS DRIVERAXLE_SUBMISSIONS_1_MONTH
FROM DRIVER WHERE ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True' 
AND TERMINAL_NUMBER IN (SELECT UNIQUE FIRST_FIELD_INSERT FROM SITE WHERE FAX_PHONE_NUMBER = :DIVISION)
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Where is my rolled up values, from the first union?

Comment: I found it :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not looked at your code...given the lack of formatting, it's not easy to follow.

However, when I've used UNION in the past to provide rolled up values, I've included  extra columns that provides a way for me to differentiate between details and totals.  These extra columns is also used as the first column to `ORDER BY`

Example:

```
select                       
  digits(HCUSNR) as Cust_Num,
  CCUSNM, 
  char(HINVNR),
  hinamt,
-- Control fields                  
  ' ' concat digits(HCMPCL),       
  case                             
    when HTRCDE in ('A', 'E', 'R') 
         then ' LVL3'              
    else  ' LVL1'                  
  end,                             
  HCUSNR, DDVDSC, HDIVSN           
UNION ALL 

select    
    ' ',  
    'Daily Invoice Total',
    ' ',
    sum(hinamt),
-- Control Fields                                     
    ' ' concat digits(HCMPCL), ' LVL2', 0, ' ', HDIVSN
group by            
    HDIVSN, HCMPCL  
--Following order by applies to entire results set  
order by 5,6,7,8,9
```

But the above was written close to 20 years ago...

If I needed to do it today, I'd use the grouping sets, rollup, and cube functionality that IBM has added to the DB.

What platform and version of DB2 are you using?  Are grouping sets, rollup and/or cube an option?

Comment: Thanks I was being silly, it was on the end of the query